# Powershell user creation script - leave fields blank?

Tags: powershell

I have created a powerhell that works just fine. However from yesterday untill today, I can't leave mobile field and ipPhone field "blank" by hitting enter to continue my script. It seems like I have to enter some numbers to the field for my script to work - but sometimes when we create users do do not know the mobile and ipphone in advance.
Therefor i want to ask if anyone know what to add in order to have the ability to hit enter to leave the fields blank and add the numbers at another later time?

My script:

```
$Mobile = Read-Host "Type mobile number (leave blank and hit enter if you do not know the mobile number yet"
$ipPhone = Read-Host "Indtast IpPhone number (leave blank and hit enter if you do not know the IpPhone number yet)"

New-ADUser `
    -Mobile "$Mobile" `
    -OfficePhone "$Mobile" `
    -OtherAttributes @{'ipPhone' = $ipPhone} `
```

It works if we type in the numbers in both Mobile and ipPhone field - but we want to leave the fields blanks sometimes - and that has worked before.

This is the error when leaving the fields blanks:

```
New-ADUser : The server is unwilling to process the request
At line:23 char:2
+  New-ADUser `
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=Jakob Hansen...faldvarme,DC=dk:String) [New-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

Comment: Hi @JM1337dk  try to make a if statement to check if some value is null then use some text also

Comment: Hi @KemalK. - If i type in some texts aswell it works...

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

Use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting)

```
# ask someone to give the mobile and ipPhone numbers. THESE CAN BE LEFT EMPTY
$Mobile  = Read-Host "Type mobile number (leave blank and hit enter if you do not know the mobile number yet"
$ipPhone = Read-Host "Indtast IpPhone number (leave blank and hit enter if you do not know the IpPhone number yet)"

# Create a Hashtable and fill in all parameters of which you are ABSOLUTELY sure they have a valid content.
# Leave out the unknown parameters like $Mobile and $ipPhone from above
# below is just a demo
$userParams = @{
    SamAccountName        = 'HansenJ'
    Name                  = 'Jakob Hansen'
    Givenname             = 'Jakob'
    Surname               = 'Hanses'
    Title                 = 'Test User'
    Department            = 'IT'
    userPrincipalName     = 'jakob.hansen@faldvarme.com'
    EmailAddress          = 'jakob.hansen@faldvarme.com'
    AccountPassword       = 'SomePa$$w0rd' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    Enabled               = $true
    ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
    CannotChangePassword  = $false
    # etc. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-aduser
}


# Now you add items to the above $userParams Hashtable ONLY IF THEY ARE NOT EMPTY
# if they are empty, these parameters will NOT become part of the splatting Hashtable
if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Mobile)) {
    $userParams['MobilePhone'] = $Mobile
    $userParams['OfficePhone'] = $Mobile
}
if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ipPhone)) {
    $userParams['OtherAttributes'] = @{'ipPhone' = $ipPhone}
}

# Finally create the new user

# if you are NOT a Domain Admnin, you need to append -Credential (Get-Credential -Message "Please enter Admin credentials here")
New-ADUser @userParams
```

Comment: it does not work using splatting. Same error occours.

Comment: @JM1337dk It does work, but it all depends on what you put in the `$userParams` Hashtable. You need more than the example Name here like the **required** `SamAccountName` which cannot be empty. Show us how you try it and we can tell you what's wrong

Comment: $userParams = @{
    Name = '$name'
    Givenname = '$Givenname'
    Surname = '$Surname'
    SamAccountName ='$SamAccountname'
    Mobile = '$Mobile'
    ipPhone = '$ipPhone'
    Title = '$Title'
    userPrincipalName = '$UserPrincipalName'
}




if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Mobile)) {
    $userParams['MobilePhone'] = $Mobile
    $userParams['OfficePhone'] = $Mobile
}
if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ipPhone)) {
    $userParams['OtherAttributes'] = @{'ipPhone' = $ipPhone}
}

Comment: @JM1337dk Leave out the parameters that could be empty and remove the single quotes around your variables

Comment: like this then? $userParams = @{
    Name = $name
    Givenname = $Givenname
    Surname = $Surname
    SamAccountName =$SamAccountname
    Mobile = 
    ipPhone =
    Title = $Title
    userPrincipalName = $UserPrincipalName
}


if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Mobile)) {
    $userParams['MobilePhone'] = $Mobile
    $userParams['OfficePhone'] = $Mobile
}
if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ipPhone)) {
    $userParams['OtherAttributes'] = @{'ipPhone' = $ipPhone}
}

Comment: @JM1337dk yep, that should do it

Comment: the same issue occours.. New-ADUser : The server is unwilling to process the request
At line:23 char:2
+  New-ADUser `

Comment: @JM1337dk Yes, that is because you still add $null parameters to the Hashtable with `Mobile = ipPhone =` That is wrong. You should ONLY add these if you are certain they are not empty. I have now rewritten the code with a much larger example for you

Comment: if($Mobile) {
   $Mobile
}else {
   $mobile = $null
   }
it works if I add this to my script. But how do I add iPhone aswell?

Comment: @JM1337dk Didn't you see that second test in my code?